IPython in VS Code : garbage collector apparently knows about variable before instantiation
I was trying to write a Python object tracker using gc.get_objects() to be used inside an existing and rather complex IPython notebook in VS Code to track potential memory "leaks" or forgotten data sets. I wanted to be able to track when new objects are instantiated and when they are deleted/collected and hence disappear from gc.get_objects().
During this, I encountered a situation, which I cannot explain.
The condensed minimal example is as follows:
1st cell:
import gc

__objs = gc.get_objects()
_objs = [id(o) for o in __objs]

#del __objs

2nd cell:
variable = ["test"]

3rd cell:
id(variable) in _objs

Running these 3 cells either manually or using "run all" results in the last cell to evaluate to "False", as expected. But if the "del __objs" statement in the 1st cell is un-commented, then the last cell evaluates to "True", which does not make sense to me at all.
Running everything in one cell or inside a .py file results in the correct "False" evaluation.
What exactly is going on here? How can the id from a variable, that is instantiated in the second cell end up in _objs, but only if __objs is deleted? And why does this happen only wit 3 separate cells?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

How are you able to use in __objs after deleting __objs? It should have gotten an error saying the variable is not defined.

Basically, there were objects whose only reference lived in __objs. Delete the list, you delete those objects, and whatever ID number was associated with them is available to be used for ["test"].

That the id is beeing reused makes total sense and answers my question. Thanks a lot !!
